# Specify Multiple Criteria for Array Elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am reading the docs for mongodb [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#single-element-satisfies-criteria),
I am not able to understand these two commands and the different between them.

```
db.users.find( { finished: { $elemMatch: { $gt: 15, $lt: 20 } } } )
```

My Understanding : At least one element needs to satisfy both the conditions together.

and

> **Combination of Elements Satisfies the Criteria** ...one element can satisfy the greater than 15 condition and another element can satisfy
>   the less than 20 condition, or a single element can satisfy both

```
db.users.find( { finished: { $gt: 15, $lt: 20 } } )
```

**Question : How range matching on arrays happen**?
Is it like if one element satisfies `$gt:15`, this condition is used up and other elements are check for the rest conditions i.e. `$lt:20`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand what the documentation is saying you first need to understand how range query with array works.

Suppose you have the following document in your collection:

```
{ "finished" : [ 27, 3 ] },
{ "finished" : 17 }
```

The first query:

```
db.users.find( { "finished": { "$elemMatch": { "$gt": 15, "$lt": 20 } } } )
```

Will only return the document where "finished" is an array. This is because [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator only matches documents where the field is an array and where a single element satisfy all the query criteria.

But the second query:

```
db.users.find( { "finished": { "$gt": 15, "$lt": 20 } } )
```

will return both documents which is probably not what you want as `27` is greater than `20` and `3` is less than `15`. This is because `27` matches the first criteria and `3` the second. This behavior is what is mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#combination-of-elements-satisfies-the-criteria).

> ...one element can satisfy the greater than 15 condition and another element can satisfy the less than 20 condition, or a single element can satisfy both:

#### Conclusion:

Range queries against arrays will match as far as one or multiple elements in the array that match all the query criteria.

#### Lesson:

Don't use range query with arrays. You will get unexpected result.

Comment: I understood your first query but want to know how range matching happens on arrays. Check edited question in bolds. What if we had arrays as [1,2,3],  [21,22,23] and [16,999,999] for second query?

Comment: @BangOperator If your array look like that only the `[16, 999, 999]` will be returned because `15<16<20`  I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have these two documents in our collection:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57548c14da05625a928404fd"),
        "finished" : [16, 21]
},
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57548c1bda05625a928404fe"),
        "finished" : [3, 36]
}
```

Suppose you want all documents where the finished array contains at least one element that is greater than 15 and less than 20 (Obviously only `16` in first document matches with this criteria). If you issue:

```
db.users.find( { finished: { $gt: 15, $lt: 20 } } )
```

Instead of just matching with the first document, it would match with both of them. Why?

The problem with the preceding query was that the field references aren't restricted to a single `finished` element. So, this query will match as long as one of the `finished` element is greater that 15 and the other is less than 20, but what you want is for both attributes to apply to the same finished element. The [*Combination of Elements Satisfies the Criteria*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#combination-of-elements-satisfies-the-criteria) section in MongoDB documentation stated this fact by:

> The following example queries for documents where the finished array
>   contains elements that in some combination satisfy the query
>   conditions; e.g., one element can satisfy the greater than 15
>   condition and another element can satisfy the less than 20 condition,
>   or a single element can satisfy both

In order to restrict the matching process, you should use the `$elemMatch` operator:

```
db.users.find( { finished: { $elemMatch: { $gt: 15, $lt: 20 } } } )
```